# Unable to locate package, no valid OpenPGP data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing on Ubuntu trying to get through the steps and have tried to install on 2 different machines. When I try to install the certs using wget ( h t t p) //packages.ros.org/ros.key -o | sudo apt-key add - I get

no valid OpenPGP data found

When I try to install ros with sudo  apt-get-install-ros-base i get:

E: Unable to locate ros-hydro-ros-base

I think everything else is configured. Anyone point me in the right direction here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157766/unable-to-locate-package,-no-valid-openpgp-data/) by [robauto](https://answers.ros.org/users/15226/robauto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-04-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're having trouble adding the key for the ROS repositories. You may want to try downloading and adding the key in separate steps:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key
sudo apt-key add ros.key
```

Then you should be able to install ROS by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-base
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix](https://answers.ros.org/users/18799/felix/) on 2014-06-06**:
Hi Ahendrix,

I am also blocked by the same problem. I have tried what you proposed. Got the following result,

felix@felix-notebook:~$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -o - | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
felix@felix-notebook:~$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key
--2014-06-06 16:36:23--  http://packages.ros.org/ros.key
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 140.211.166.134
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|140.211.166.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1162 (1.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: `ros.key.4'

100%[======================================================================================================>] 1,162       --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-06-06 16:36:23 (54.9 MB/s) - `ros.key.4' saved [1162/1162]

felix@felix-notebook:~$ sudo apt-key add ros.key
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Appreciate it very much if you could give me any idea to solve this.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-06**:
Sorry; you comment is completely unreadable without formatting. Can you please ask this as a new question?